# Get reference to ApplicationContext with @ImportResource annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:path-to-application-context.xml")
public class SocketMain extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
  public static void main(String [] args) {
     // ...
  }
}
```

I want to get access to the application context in my `main` function so I can fetch one of my defined beans. I can't autowire it since you cannot autowire a static variable. Is there a way to get a reference to the applicationContext that is loaded with the `@ImportResource` annotation?

My fallback is to just load the applicationContext in `main` like so:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("path-to-application-context.xml");`
```

But I don't want to load it twice.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way to retrieve your application context in Spring and retrieve a bean. This should be placed in your main function

```
ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(SocketMain.class, args);
SomeClass sc = ctx.getBean(SomeClass.class);
sc.testRun();
```

You should also be able to retrieve the context with `@Autowired`.

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext context;
```

Comment: This ctx help me a lot.Thanks